# ZAP security testing in Mobile - unable to launch app or browser via connected wifi after changing Proxy to manual in mobile ( both android and IOS )

Tags: security, owasp, zap, security-testing

First I did the below mentioned steps:

"
First you need to install the certificate in your mobile device for ZAP to record it. You can do that by following steps:

Open ZAP
Go to Tools
Click in Options then click in Dynamic SSL Certificate and generate the new and save it.
Then you need to send that certificate to your device, make sure you name the file as "zap"
In the local proxy, set the address "empty"
Then, you need to configure your android/ios application network configuration You can do that by following steps:

Go to advance setting of the network
Click in proxy and set it as "manual"
Then, you need to enter the proxy server to your computer IP address and port to proxy set in the ZAP."

After these I tried to open browser and app. I am unable to open it. I am getting weak security warning and "Privacy Warning" in my mobile.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error, had to do extra step to trust manually installed certificate profiles. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204477.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).